# Override tax_query with pre_get_posts to include other term_ids on a single category

Tags: pre-get-posts, tax-query

I'm trying to include more than one term_id(multiple checkboxes filter) on a single category page.
I managed to recollect enough to build a tax_query with pre_get_posts, but now it seems, I have two tax_queries, one is in WP_Query->query_vars and the other is just in WP_Query(that one is of WP_Tax_Query type):

```
object(WP_Query)#1968 (50) {
  ["query"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["product_cat"]=>
    string(77) "parent-category-slug/slug-of-the-category"
  }
  ["query_vars"]=>
  array(59) {
    ["product_cat"]=>
    string(56) "slug-of-the-category"
    ["error"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["m"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["p"]=>
    int(0)
    ["post_parent"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["subpost"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["subpost_id"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["attachment"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["attachment_id"]=>
    int(0)
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["pagename"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["page_id"]=>
    int(0)
    ["second"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["minute"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["hour"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["day"]=>
    int(0)
    ["monthnum"]=>
    int(0)
    ["year"]=>
    int(0)
    ["w"]=>
    int(0)
    ["category_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tag"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["cat"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tag_id"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["author_name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["feed"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["tb"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["paged"]=>
    int(0)
    ["meta_key"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["preview"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["s"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["sentence"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["title"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["fields"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["menu_order"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["embed"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["category__in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["category__not_in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["category__and"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["post__in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["post__not_in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["post_name__in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["tag__in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["tag__not_in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["tag__and"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["tag_slug__in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["tag_slug__and"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["post_parent__in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["post_parent__not_in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["author__in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["author__not_in"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["orderby"]=>
    string(16) "menu_order title"
    ["order"]=>
    string(3) "ASC"
    ["meta_query"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["tax_query"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(4) {
        ["taxonomy"]=>
        string(11) "product_cat"
        ["field"]=>
        string(7) "term_id"
        ["terms"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          int(47)
          [1]=>
          int(834)
        }
        ["operator"]=>
        string(2) "IN"
      }
    }
    ["wc_query"]=>
    string(13) "product_query"
    ["posts_per_page"]=>
    int(12)
    ["post_type"]=>
    string(7) "product"
  }
  ["tax_query"]=>
  object(WP_Tax_Query)#4683 (6) {
    ["queries"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["taxonomy"]=>
        string(11) "product_cat"
        ["terms"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(56) "slug-of-the-category"
        }
        ["field"]=>
        string(4) "slug"
        ["operator"]=>
        string(2) "IN"
        ["include_children"]=>
        bool(true)
      }
    }
    ["relation"]=>
    string(3) "AND"
    ["table_aliases":protected]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["queried_terms"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["product_cat"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["terms"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(56) "slug-of-the-category"
        }
        ["field"]=>
        string(4) "slug"
      }
    }
    ["primary_table"]=>
    NULL
    ["primary_id_column"]=>
    NULL
  }
  ["meta_query"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["date_query"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["queried_object"]=>
  object(WP_Term)#4649 (10) {
    ["term_id"]=>
    int(1059)
    ["name"]=>
    string(59) "Name of the category"
    ["slug"]=>
    string(56) "slug-of-the-category"
    ["term_group"]=>
    int(0)
    ["term_taxonomy_id"]=>
    int(1059)
    ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(11) "product_cat"
    ["description"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["parent"]=>
    int(416)
    ["count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["filter"]=>
    string(3) "raw"
  }
  ["queried_object_id"]=>
  int(1059)
  ["post_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["current_post"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["in_the_loop"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["comment_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["current_comment"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["found_posts"]=>
  int(0)
  ["max_num_pages"]=>
  int(0)
  ["max_num_comment_pages"]=>
  int(0)
  ["is_single"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_preview"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_page"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_archive"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["is_date"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_year"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_month"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_day"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_time"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_author"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_category"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_tag"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_tax"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["is_search"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_feed"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_comment_feed"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_trackback"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_home"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_privacy_policy"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_404"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_embed"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_paged"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_admin"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_attachment"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_singular"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_robots"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_favicon"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_posts_page"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["is_post_type_archive"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["query_vars_hash":"WP_Query":private]=>
  string(32) "0cab94343472426f19caa925968f6373"
  ["query_vars_changed":"WP_Query":private]=>
  bool(false)
  ["thumbnails_cached"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["stopwords":"WP_Query":private]=>
  NULL
  ["compat_fields":"WP_Query":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(15) "query_vars_hash"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "query_vars_changed"
  }
  ["compat_methods":"WP_Query":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "init_query_flags"
    [1]=>
    string(15) "parse_tax_query"
  }
}
```

This is the POC filter:

```
function a3_include_filtered_ctgs($query)
{
    if (!isset($_GET['filterCtg'])) return;

    if ($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin()) {
        var_dump($query->get('tax_query'));

        $taxquery = //$query->get('tax_query');
            array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => array_map(function ($id) {
                        return (int) $id;
                    }, explode(",", $_GET['filterCtg'])),
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                )
            );

        if ($query->get('suppress_filters')) {
            $query->set('suppress_filters', false);
        }

        $query->set('tax_query', $taxquery);        

        var_dump($query);
    }
}

if (A3_DEBUG === true) {
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'a3_include_filtered_ctgs');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> but now it seems, I have two tax_queries, one is in
> WP_Query->query_vars and the other is just in WP_Query

That is normal.

- `WP_Query::$query_vars` is an array of query vars merged with the default ones for [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).

  So if you do `$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_status' => 'publish' ) )` (or `$query = new WP_Query( 'post_status=publish' )`) and then later do `$query->set( 'tax_query', array( ... ) )`, then `$query->query_vars` would contain both `post_status` and `tax_query`, as well as other vars like `posts_per_page`, `post_type`, etc.
- `WP_Query::$tax_query` is an instance of the [`WP_Tax_Query` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_tax_query/) and is used by `WP_Query` for generating the SQL's `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses for the taxonomy query (`tax_query`) in the `$query_vars` array.

Answer (score 0):

@Sally CJ, thanks for the clearup. However in the end I removed product_cat query variable using `$query->set('product_cat', null);`

It seems to have done the trick, but I'll have to properly test it.

Comment: I did notice that `product_cat` query var in `query_vars`, but anyway, my answer was only for explaining the `tax_query` in `WP_Query::$query_vars` vs the `WP_Query::$tax_query` *property*. :)